# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_DONHANG'

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE P_2_3 AS
    PROCEDURE P_DONHANG 
    (
        i_v_SODH char ,
        i_v_ngaygiaohang date
    );
    END P_2_3;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY P_2_3 AS
    PROCEDURE P_DONHANG 
    (
        i_v_SODH char ,
        i_v_ngaygiaohang date
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE DONHANG
        SET NGAYGIAOHANG =i_v_ngaygiaohang
        WHERE SODH =i_v_SODH;
    END P_DONHANG ;
END P_2_3;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;
BEGIN
    P_2_3.P_DONHANG(&SODH ,&NGAYgiaohang);
END;
```

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_DONHANG'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: What values are you using for &SODH and &NGAYgiaohang when you run your script? Probably there's a problem converting the string you input to a date for &NGAYgiaohang. Try declaring i_v_ngaygiaohang as a varchar2 and doing a explicit conversion: TO_DATE(i_v_ngaygiaohang, 'your_date_format') to discard that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

We're missing the crucial part here - the way you called the procedure and parameters you provided.

Package and the body seem to be OK; I don't have your table so I just commented the `UPDATE` out as it is currently irrelevant.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p_2_3 AS
  2      PROCEDURE p_donhang (
  3          i_v_sodh         CHAR,
  4          i_v_ngaygiaohang DATE
  5      );
  6
  7  END p_2_3;
  8  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p_2_3 AS
  2
  3      PROCEDURE p_donhang (
  4          i_v_sodh         CHAR,
  5          i_v_ngaygiaohang DATE
  6      ) AS
  7      BEGIN
  8          null;
  9          /*
 10          UPDATE donhang
 11          SET
 12              ngaygiaohang = i_v_ngaygiaohang
 13          WHERE
 14              sodh = i_v_sodh;
 15          */
 16      END p_donhang;
 17
 18  END p_2_3;
 19  /

Package body created.

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;
```

OK, let's call the procedure:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2      p_2_3.p_donhang(&sodh, &ngaygiaohang);
  3  END;
  4  /
Enter value for sodh: 1
Enter value for ngaygiaohang: 2
old   2:     p_2_3.p_donhang(&sodh, &ngaygiaohang);
new   2:     p_2_3.p_donhang(1, 2);
    p_2_3.p_donhang(1, 2);
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_DONHANG'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

See? That's the error you got. I don't know which values you used, but - obviously - you used something invalid. The first parameter's datatype should be a string (you set it to `CHAR`; consider `VARCHAR2`), and the second one should be a valid `DATE` datatype value. For example:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for sodh: 'A'
Enter value for ngaygiaohang: date '2022-05-01'
old   2:     p_2_3.p_donhang(&sodh, &ngaygiaohang);
new   2:     p_2_3.p_donhang('A', date '2022-05-01');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

- 'A' is a string
- `date '2022-05-01'` is date literal (that's *today*)

I suggest you try the same. If it still fails, now you know which information you should share with us.